# Problem with the output of the engine control signal

Tags: microcontroller, c, 8051, keil

Program to control three DC motor levels and display speed (RPM) on a 7-segment LED using 8051. Use external interrupt 0 to read pulse from encoder. When compiling on keil C there is no error, but simulation on proteus cannot output control signal from pin P2.5. When I delete  `display` function in `main` it gets controllable. I think the problem is in `display` function.

Here is the code:

```
#include <reg51.h>
#define on 0
#define off 1
sbit led1 = P2^0;
sbit led2 = P2^1;
sbit led3 = P2^2;
sbit led4 = P2^3;
sbit in = P3^2;
sbit out = P2^5;
sbit low = P1^0;
sbit medium = P1^1;
sbit high = P1^2;
sbit stop = P1^3;

unsigned int count = 0, n, t = 0;
char so[] = {0xc0, 0xf9, 0xa4, 0xb0, 0x99, 0x92, 0x82, 0xf8, 0x80, 0x90}; // for number 0->9

void delay_ms (int time)
{
    unsigned int i,j;
    for (i = 1; i < time ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 125; j++);  //delay 1ms
    }
}
void init()
{   
    in = 1;
    IT0 = 1;
    EX0 = 1;
    EA = 1;
    TMOD = 0x10;        
    ET1 = 1;
    TR1 = 1;
}
void demXung() interrupt 0
{
    count++;    
}
void timer1() interrupt 3
{
    t++;
    TH1 = 0xfc;
    TL1 = 0x18;
    TR1 = 1;
    if (t>=60)
        {
            n = count;
            count = 0;
            t = 0;
        }
}
void display (unsigned int dem)
{
    unsigned char nghin, tram, chuc, donVi;
    int i;
    nghin = dem/1000;
    tram = (dem%1000)/100;
    chuc = (dem%100)/10;
    donVi = dem%10;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
        {
            led1 = on; P0 = so[nghin]; delay_ms(100); led1 = off;
            led2 = on; P0 = so[tram]; delay_ms(100); led2 = off;
            led3 = on; P0 = so[chuc]; delay_ms(100); led3 = off;
            led4 = on; P0 = so[donVi]; delay_ms(100); led4 = off;
        }
}
void dung()
{
    if (stop == 0)
    {
        low = medium = high = 1;
        out = 0;
    }
}

void thap()
{
    if (low == 0)
    {
        medium = high = 1;
        low = 0;
        out = 1;
        delay_ms(30);
        out = 0;
        delay_ms(70);
    }
}
void trungBinh()
{
    if (medium == 0)
    {
        low = high = 1;
        medium = 0;
        out = 1;
        delay_ms(50);
        out = 0;
        delay_ms(50);
    }
}

void cao()
{
    if (high == 0)
    {
        low = medium = 1;
        high = 0;
        out = 1;
        delay_ms(90);
        out = 0;
        delay_ms(10);
    }
}
void main()
{
    init();
    out = 0;    
    while (1)   
    {
        display(n);
        dung();
        thap();
        trungBinh();
        cao();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display function has four 100ms delays and loops 50 times - that works out to 20 seconds. Whilst that is happening, nothing else apart from your interrupts are getting processed.

You need to re-arrange how you update your display. It looks like you are using multiplexing, so you might want to use a timer to generate regular interrupts, say,10ms. Update 1 digit each interrupt and you won't need to use delay_ms(). Once you do this, the rest of your code will be processed much faster than every 20 seconds.